# stuck at calling some methods in C++ to create a menu

Tags: c++, class, oop, set

I have a class `ComplexesSet` which represent a set of complexes numbers. I have to use this class to write a program which reads the complex numbers from keyboard and create a menu like that: press 1 to add a number in the set, press 2 to delete a number from set and press 0 to exit the program.

This is my program:
HEADER FILE

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define DIMMAX 10;

class Complex {
    int re, im;
public:
    Complex() {
        re = im = 0;
    }
    Complex(int re, int im) {
        this->re = re;
        this->im = im;
    }
    void display() {
        cout << " (" << re << ", " << im << " ) ";
    }
    int equal(Complex c2); // check the equality between 2 complex numbers.
    void read(); // reads a complex number
};

class ComplexesSet {
    Complex* v; // the complex numbera array
    int dim; // the maximum dimension of the array
    int n; // the current number of complex numbers in the set
public:
    ComplexesSet();
    ComplexesSet(int d);
    ~ComplexesSet();
    void addNumber(Complex); // add a number in set
    void deleteNumber(Complex); // delete a number from set
    void displaySet(); // display the set
};
```

METHODS FILE

```
#include "multime.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Complex::equal(Complex c2) {
    if (this->re == c2.re && this->im == c2.im) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void Complex::read() {
    cout << "Enter the real part: ";
    cin >> this->re;
    cout << "Enter the imaginary part: ";
    cin >> this->im;
    cout << endl;
}

ComplexesSet::ComplexesSet() {
    cout << "Set of complexes numbers: ";
    dim = DIMMAX;
    v = new Complex[dim];
    n = 0;
}

ComplexesSet::ComplexesSet(int d) {
    cout << "ComplexesSet(" << d << ")";
    dim = d;
    v = new Complex[dim];
    n = 0;
}

ComplexesSet::~ComplexesSet() {
    cout << "~ComplexesSet" << endl;
    if (v) {
        delete[] v;
    }
    v = nullptr;
    dim = -1;
    n = -1;
}

void ComplexesSet::addNumber(Complex num) {
    int ok = 0;
    if (n < dim) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (v[i].equal(num)) {
                ok = 1;
                i = n + 1;
            }
        }
        if (ok) {
            cout << "This element is already in the set.";
        }
        else {
            v[n] = num;
            n++;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "The set is full.";
    }
}

void ComplexesSet::deleteNumber(Complex num) {
    int i;
    if (n != 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (v[i].equal(num)) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                cout << "This element does not exists.";
            }
        }
        if (i < n) {
            n = n - 1;
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
                v[j] = v[j + 1];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "The set is empty.";
    }
}

void ComplexesSet::displaySet() {
    cout << "\n The set: {";
    if (n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            v[i].display();
        }
    }
    cout << "}.\n\n";
}
```

MAIN FILE:

```
#include "multime.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ComplexesSet m;
    Complex num;
    int option;
    int x;
    do {
        cout << endl << "1 - ADD A NUMBER\n 2 - DELETE A NUMBER\n 0 - EXIT THE PROGRAM";
        cin >> option;
        switch (option) {
        case 1:
            cout << endl << "Enter the number you want to add: ";
            num.read();
            //? How to call addNumber method from ComplexesSet class?
            // m.displaySet ?;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << endl << "Enter the number you want to delete: ";
            num.read();
            //? How to call deleteNumber method from ComplexesSet class?
            // m.displaySet ?;
            break;
        }
    } while (option >= 1 && option <= 2);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I got stuck in the main file. How to call the addNumber and deleteNumber methods in order to add and delete a complex number from the set? Also, after pressing "1" or "2", after I read the number, I need to display the set.

Comment: Your C++ textbook should have plenty of examples of calling methods of class objects. What, ***specifically***, don't you understand about the topic of invoking class methods?

Comment: Well, let's say I call the method addNumber, so I have ```num.read(); m.addNumber()``` How to add the number I read in the set? I know I should give the number I read to the method as parameter but I don't understand how

Comment: You've written the `ComplexesSet::addNumber` member function, right? What happens if you do `m.addNumber(num);`?

Comment: Ok, can you look at one of examples in your C++ textbook of calling class methods? How does it look like? Unfortunately, stackoverflow.com is not a replacement for a C++ textbook, and you should always look to your textbook for basic information like that. Feel free to ask if something ***specific*** in your textbook is unclear to you.

Comment: I solved the problem . I am so stupid. Thank you for the help. Sometimes I get stuck or I don't "see" the solution of my problem. Thanks again